# Elements added dynamically disappear

Tags: android, android-layout

In my application I dynamically add elements (EditText, RadioButton, CheckBox, Spinner, ImageView ...) to a ScrollView, but lately, in certain phones, the elements disappear, but when the app is re-installed, the problem is solved, even the problem it also appears with some elements of a ListView (disappear). Do you have any idea why this happens?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe it has to do with the Android version on certain phones.

It's really hard to tell without you supplying more information and/or your code.

What exactly do you mean by "disappear" and "reinstall"?

Comment: Disappear: Some Elements in listview doesn't show.
Reinstall: When the app is uninstalled and intalled again.